# Reset Password Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, passwords, reset

Is there a page already setup for a user to reset their password? E.g /user/ for user registration, /user/x/edit/ for editing your profile, is there a /user/reset/ or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is:

http://mysite.com/user/password

Comment: When you click on the link in the email it takes me to my profile page (/user) which simply displays my first name, surname and country only. In order to change my password I need to edit my profile first, however this then asks me for my current password which I obviously don't know?

Comment: Having an unconditional password reset link for a logged in user is a security risk; if someone leaves their account logged in at a machine, even for a few minutes, someone could come along and change their password. This is why the user must put in their current password before setting a new one. If you log out and go to `user/password` you'll see the form you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that, however when I logout, go to user/password and enter my email address I receive an email to my inbox asking me to click on the link. When I do this I am taken to the site which then says "This is a one-time login for admin and will expire on 2012-Apr-20.
Click on this button to log in to the site and change your password.
This login can be used only once." When I click the login button underneath it logs me in and takes me to my profile page (/user). However, how do I then set my new password? Surely I must be able to do so now it has logged me in?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that last comment, I'm using a rule that redirects the user after login to the profile page, therefore the page to create a new password was being redirected so I was never seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is 'user/password' where you get to a page to enter your email to receive the one-time login-link.